# RabbitMQ Producer is stuck in golang

Tags: go, rabbitmq

Im new to golang and rabbitmq, I have written a simple producer like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    server()
}

func server() {
    conn, ch, q := getQueue()
    defer conn.Close()
    defer ch.Close()

    msg := amqp.Publishing{
        ContentType: "text/plain",
        Body:        []byte("Hello RabbitMQ"),
    }

    ch.Publish("", q.Name, false, false, msg)
}

func getQueue() (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, *amqp.Queue) {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare("hello",
        false, //durable bool,
        false, //autoDelete bool,
        false, //exclusive bool,
        false,
        nil)
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare queue")
    return conn, ch, &q
}

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", msg, err))
    }
}
```

When I run this it doesnt exit niether does it throw any error messages. In the RabbitMQ management console I can see the Queue but there is no data in it and only shows NaN.

Comment: Very good, and now only use debugger or fmt.Println and find the command where your program stuck

Comment: in amqp, [`Channel.Publish`](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Publish) returns an error, maybe you should check the error returned if any.

Comment: it does exit, for me at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably an issue with your setup. I faced a similar issue and tried with a different Erlang and RabbitMQ installation.
Try uninstalling both Erlang and RabbitMQ and maybe use an older stable version.

Alternatively use the official RabbitMQ docker image. Follow the [Docker RabbitMQ Docs](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/rabbitmq/) for setting it up. :)